# How to send newly created user info from keycloak to spring application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, keycloak

I'm running my application on tomcat,I tried to integrate it to keycloak for SSO.I used spring security adapter for keycloak integration.Now I modified the registration page of keycloak as per my need.The user created succesfully in keycloak.What is the way to send that user info to spring application inorder to store it in my application database.What's the thing I need to do in keycloak to transmit data and What I need to do in spring to retrieve this information.